# how to publish task pane app to an organization app catalog - office 2013 apps

Tags: office-2013, office-app

I have developed an app for office 2013(word, excel and powerpoint) using VS2012 and Microsoft Office Developer Tools for VS2012.

Now i want to allow test team to test my app. Following this article [Publish apps for Office and SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220037.aspx).

> - Publishing task pane and content apps to an organization app catalog
>
>   For task pane and content apps, IT departments can deploy and
>     configure private shared folder app catalogs to provide the same
>     Office-solution catalog experience that the Office Store provides.

Then i followed that article [How to: Create a network share catalog for task pane and content apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123503.aspx), so anyone in my network or can access my folder be able to add the app into his office

Now my problem is I don't know how to do the last step. for some ***mysterious*** reasons there is no documentation for that step and i'm stuck. Can anyone give me hint about that.

Answer (score 1):

in the docs you linked to I see that the last step is "8.Select the Show in Menu check box, and then choose OK".

This last step refers the the trusted app catalog in the trust center settings available under the options button on the file screen.  You will be prompted to restart your office application after you make this change and click OK.  After that your manifests from the network location you added should show up in the insert app window.

The apps you have the manifests for in the folder should now show up in the insert box and will load from where you have them hosted for testing.  If the apps don't appear in the insert box you may want to double check how you entered the network path in the trust settings.